# How to use it store method with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

First use as below;

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Hall::create($request->all());
        return "not important";
    }
```

Second use as below;

```
 public function store(Request $request)
        {
           if($request){
            Hall::create($request->all());
            return "not important";
           } 
        }
```

Do you need control with `if`? Which makes more sense

Comment: no need to use if

Comment: but why brother?

Comment: go look for the create() method inside the source code of laravel and you will have a better understanding of it.

Comment: that is, as a measure against attack from the outside.

Comment: I think you should validate the request. You should check the following link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation 

and that is protect against attack

Comment: @ufuk laravel provide `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance with every request which contains some metadata, so it won't be empty

Answer (score 1):

No need really for `If statement`.
What the `create` method does, is create a new Element (in your case Hall), and save it in the database, taking into consideration the possible attributes in your model.
So when you define your model (Hall), you should have something like follow:

```
public Hall extends Model
{
    public $table = 'halls';
    protected $fillable = ['column1', 'column2'];// all attributes that should be filled in with create method.
}
```

Then, for the validation of your request, you can make a request `php artisan make:request HallRequest`, and there you defin your validation.